# Share screenshot on Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the following code to take a screenshot on my iPhone and save it to the photo album. What I would like is a share button to automatically send this screenshot and to Facebook. Does anyone have any ideas how to implement?

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)view
{
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return img;
}

- (void)saveScreenshotToPhotosAlbum:(UIView *)view
{
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self captureView:self.view], nil, nil, nil);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setUpData];

CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
frame.size.height -= 90;

self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

UIBarButtonItem *shareBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(saveScreenshotToPhotosAlbum:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:shareBtn];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the iOS6 built-in Facebook integration.
Include the `Social` framwork in `Build Phases`
The code should look bi similar to this snipped:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]){
    mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"Some Text"];
    [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[self captureView:self.view]];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

*Note this will not "automatically" share the screenshot but it will attach it to a Facebook Compose Sheet and the user can post it if he/she wants to. To do it automatically, you will need to do a deeper Facebook integration and the user should give permission for your app to post on his/her wall. This again should be done with the `Social` framework or `ShareKit` if the project `Deployment target` is bellow iOS 6.0

Comment: Ok thanks, how do I turn than into a button on the navigation bar?

Comment: Jus add this code in your `saveScreenshotToPhotosAlbum:` method and it should work.

Comment: I added Social framework and imports. Now I get use of undeclared identifier 'mySLComposerSheet'

Comment: Just need to fix the above otherwise looks great, a very useful feature to have on any App snap and share.

Comment: declared in h file, fixes it and it works like a dream!Thank you so much!
    `SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;`

Comment: Oh, yes.. Forgot about the property you need to declare. You can refactor it to not need a property but the current implementation needs one. I'm glad I helped you.