# Get Status of IOS SaveToPhotoAlbum

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimage

Is it possible to get the status of the function SaveToPhotoAlbum Function for UIImage?

I'm trying to share the photo asap after I saved it and I need to know when the photo is done being saved to the photo album.

The closest example I got was [Share screenshot on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241377/share-screenshot-on-facebook)
or [xamarin ios screenshot and email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358354/xamarin-ios-screenshot-and-email)

which I tried to do it with the email example but the Image I got was white as I believe that I tried getting the UIImage before it is actually done saving to the photo album/saving the frame.

This is how I save the screenshot

```
    public void ScreenGrab()
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Frame.Size);

        //new iOS 7 method to snapshot
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.DrawViewHierarchy (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Frame, true);

        UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();

        //saves captured frame onto album
        image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((SavedImage, error) => {
            if(error ==null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error:" + error );
            }
        });

    }
```

and this is how I get my latest screenshot

```
public UIImage GetLatestImageFromAlbum()
    {
            UIImage image = new UIImage ();
            //must return a UIImage

            //Fetch all the assets based on the format given
            var assets = PHAsset.FetchAssets (new PHFetchOptions (){ Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat (@"mediaType == " + (int)PHAssetMediaType.Image) });

            //Request Options for the Image
            var options = new PHImageRequestOptions () {
                NetworkAccessAllowed = true,
                DeliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat,
                Synchronous = true
            };

            //Must check if there is access for the photo album on iOS
            if (PHPhotoLibrary.AuthorizationStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Access Granted");
                PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageForAsset ((PHAsset)assets.LastObject, UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Bounds.Size, PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options, (UIImage result, NSDictionary info) => {
                    image = result;
                });
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("Access Denied");
            }



        return image;
    }
```

I tried calling GetLatestImageFromAlbum() when error != null but it did not work as I assume the photo has not been fully saved yet so it is unable to retrieve the photo.

I also tried calling GetLatestImageFromAlbum() directly after ScreenGrab() but the same thing happened as well, like this.

```
testIOS.ScreenGrab();
slComposer.AddImage(testIOS.GetLatestImageFromAlbum());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to fix my problem, first we have to trigger the screengrab then wait inside a update loop to check if the image is done saving which I done using a boolean, once its done, then you trigger the GrabLatestImageFromAlbum.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know in which language you want answer, but in Swift 2.2

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.imageSaved(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

func imageSaved(image: UIImage!, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: AnyObject?) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Something wrong happened.
    } else {
        // Everything is alright.
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm currently doing it in c#